# collapse variables in R if row value is true

Tags: r

I want to collapse some variables  into a single variable if the variable value is True

Eg: Data set

- A B C D E F
- F T F F...
- F F T F..
- F F F T..
- T F F F..
- F F F F....

The output I am looking for

1. New_variable

   - B
   - C
   - D
   - A
   - .

As you can see if the row value is true I would like to replace it with its corresponding column value.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

We can use `max.col` to find the column name in each row based on the TRUE value

```
i1 <- rowSums(df1) == 0
df1$New_variable <- names(df1)[max.col(df1, "first")]
df1$New_variable[i1] <- ""
```

Answer (score 1):

use `any()` to identify at least one value in the column is `TRUE`

```
df1 <- read.table(text='A B C D E F
           F T F F F F
                  F F T F F F
                  F F F T F F
                  T F F F F F
                  F F F F F F', header = TRUE)

colnames(df1)[ (apply( df1, 2, any)) ]
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```